# Cursor visible on overlapping div which has higher z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mouse-cursor

My problem is about the appearance of the cursor on an overlapping div which has a higher `z-index`.

The problem is after you click on the button, a `div` appears. Now click on the div that was previously visible. You will be able to view the cursor on the newly appeared div even though it's `z-index` is higher. This issue is in IE only not on FF or chrome.

```js
$("#y").click(function() {
  $("#u").css("display", "block");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="u" style="height:auto;zindex:999;display:none;border:3px solid red;width:300px;background-color:white;position:absolute;">
  awaeqweqweqwe<br>awqeqweqw<br>aweqweqweq<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></div>
<div contenteditable="true" style="border:2px solid black;margin-top:30px;height:100px"></div>
<input type="buton" id="y" value="askjhdka">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZpDk/1/.) - check in IE9.

Any solution to this for IE?

Comment: I have modelled my problem in a js fiddle - `http://jsfiddle.net/YZpDk/1/`.
Run this in IE9.

Comment: This appears to be an issue in all versions of IE; and not simply IE9.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and had to resolve with JS. I blurred focus on the input when the overlapping element was visible.

Comment: @ScottSimpson - I cant change the focus somehow. Its part of the functionality that is to be added .. Any other possible solution?

Comment: I hope this can solve by wrapping popup element with iFrame.

Comment: same question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716765/how-to-hide-text-cursor-below-div-element

Answer (score -1):

If you see logically, user will click on textarea if they do not want to check overlay. I think that time you should hide the overlay.

$('.textarea').focus(function(){
    $("#u").css("display","none");
});