# How to hide text cursor below div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I am new to CSS and javascript.
I have one search text box in which I can add any search value. After entering a wrong value one pop up div comes and says "no records found" (with close button to close div). after I put my cursor on text box without closing pop up. my cursor displays above the div box.
|------------------|search box
|------------------|

My text box css properties.

```
z-index: 200630; position: absolute; width: 149px; height: 21px;
overflow: visible; top: 0px; cursor: default; left: 0px;
```

My div element css prop:

```
z-index: 201350; position: absolute; width: 270px; height: 20px;
overflow: hidden; top: 0px; cursor: default; left: 0px;
```

How to hide cursor below div element.Issue occurs only in IE

I have created small jsfiddle.Issue occur in IE 8 only not FF
http://jsfiddle.net/raj31/LUaej/1/

Comment: have you tried $('.cssClassName').css('cursor', 'none');

Comment: but after I close my div element I want that cursor on text box. It should be there but below div element. is it any css properties?

Comment: Why do you need to hide the cursor? It's a tool of interaction, don't fiddle with it!

Comment: Please find attached image. how it look like.

Comment: saw attached image you can play with [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) just bind them blur to open popup event and focus to close event

Comment: @Alex kneller, Issue occurs only in IE. not on FF. so is it possible using CSS only

Comment: Which version of IE it is? Old versions of IE had a bug, having different z-layer stacks for positioned elements

Comment: I ma using IE 8. i think its stable

Comment: So one more question, having IE opened on your page, can you press F12 to run developer tools (you can install them if you don't have them from Microsoft). Then check the Browser Mode and Document Mode values displayed around of the top of the new window.

Comment: @Ipliepiora: Browser mode is IE compatible view and Document mode is IE8 standard.

Comment: I tried to set opacity property but no luck.

Comment: it is a strange behavior which i can reproduce in IE 10. an alternative could be, that you let your alert-box close, if someone click anywhere else than on the box. i don't know how to fix your exact problem. maybe it is a security "feature" of MS to prevent users for typing informations in overlayed input-fields

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/BE5Sf/), which I believe reproduces your problem.

I think the solution could be to simply blur search field on showing the dialog, like I did in the 3rd line (comment it out to get your problem):

```
 $('.seach').blur()
```

Comment: I have fiddle. Please check out what is problem is there. Issue occurs only in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/raj31/BqJ8r/

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with available IE(s)..

See reference

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/841043/blinking-text-cursor-overlapping-with-div

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to dismiss cursor while focusing your new div.
It worked for me, I am closing a div which includes username and password inputs after authentication. After enter key, cursor was blinking but, I focused logo in callback function in auth function. Now it is OK

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for this but I've just solved this bug using `document.activeElement.blur();`.